# How the Phaser3 resizes an image

Tags: phaser-framework, phaserjs

I can not understand what is the discrepancy between the expected result and what is actually.
In the first example, I set the width of the *gui-window* to the width of the screen, and the height to 0.3 of the height of the screen, placing this on the screen I found that part of the image didn't fit on the screen.

[image: core]
[result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1D4W.png)

You can make sure that the *gui-window* is cropped from the following screenshots, where I added a padding of 100 pixels when adding an image to the scene

[image: code]
[result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVrBO.png)

Can anyone explain why the Phaser behaves this way and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem is tht you are not using the function as you should.

The function `setDisplaySize` just changes the images and distorts it *([link to the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Image.html#setDisplaySize__anchor)).* that the image is cut off has probably to do with the the passed `width` and `height`. The game - scene might be smaller that the window size.
Instead of `innerHeight` / `innerWidth` you could use   `this.scene.game.config.height` / `this.scene.game.config.width`, this two properties should return the correct sze of the current *html-canvas-object*.

> **btw.:** if you want to keep the border without distortion, i recommend using *nine-slice* check out this feature *(available starting with the version 3.60 and above)*   https://labs.phaser.io/view.html?src=src/game%20objects/nine%20slice/create%20nine%20slice.js

> **btw.:** when posting question *(or answers)*, it is always better to post the code, and not a screenshot of the code.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, the problem is that innerHeight/innerWidth is not the same as the scene size